# Mesh triangulation and simplification C++ library

Tags: c++, 3d, mesh

I am looking for a C++ library to triangulate and simplify 3D mesh. My 3D meshes are potentially huge (around 3 millions vertices). It should ideally be open source. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some libraries I found:

1) CGAL

++ Does a lot of things;

-- Licensing issues;

2) GTS

++ Open source and quite easy to use;

-- Does less that CGAL

anymore ideas?

Comment: Just to mention that CGAL is also open source (GPL3+)

Answer (score 5):

***vcglib*** (http://www.vcglib.net) is a open source c++ mesh processing library that offers high quality simplification.

vcglib is the library behind MeshLab (http://www.meshlab.net) so if you find some mesh processing feature in meshlab you will probably find that feature in the vcglib

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a C++ library to triangulate and simplify 3D mesh.

In addition to the libraries suggested in other answers, I would suggest looking at open-source [MeshLib](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib#readme) C++ library, which contains very fast and precise decimation functions, see [documentation](https://meshinspector.github.io/MeshLib/html/group__DecimateGroup.html). The implemented algorithm there is based on [Surface Simplification Using Quadric Error Metrics](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E./garland/Papers/quadrics.pdf) article with several improvements and optimizations.

> My 3D meshes are potentially huge (around 3 millions vertices).

On top of that, there is a parallel version of mesh simplification specially tailored for such huge meshes. It splits the surface on smaller parts, decimates them concurrently, then merges them again, and decimates the triangles near part boundaries to avoid any visible seams, see `MR::decimateParallelMesh()` function.