# Mesh simplification library in C#

Tags: c#, rendering, mesh, simplification

Similarly to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892690/mesh-triangulation-and-simplification-c-library), I wonder which C# `mesh-simplification libraries` are available out there.

My (I believe common) problem is to reduce the computational effort  of rendering `.stl meshes`.

Comment: I've also found this on StackOverflow. Would it help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422403/good-data-structure-for-triangular-mesh

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. I was aware of CGAL and didn't know about OpenMesh and Suface Mesh. However, I am interested in C# libraries.

Comment: btw, why -1? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Humm... There is a person that created is own geometry library and aparently it is already done. The goals of this library seems to be what you are looking for:

- Implement basic geometric primitives and polygon mesh processing.
- Based on a robust numerical foundation.
- Target the .NET platform (and Mono).
- Published under a permissive open-source license allowing commercial use.

Find his git repo [here](https://github.com/govert/RobustGeometry.NET).