# How to do runtime mesh simplification with a more complicated mesh for tile-based geometry?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I'm using this mesh simplifier:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

static public class MeshColliderTools {

    public static void SnapToGrid(this Mesh mesh, float gridDelta) {
        if (gridDelta < 1e-5f)
            return;
        float inverse = 1f / gridDelta;
        var verts = mesh.vertices;
        for (int i = 0; i < verts.Length; i++) {
            verts[i].x = Mathf.RoundToInt(verts[i].x*inverse) / inverse;
            verts[i].y = Mathf.RoundToInt(verts[i].y*inverse) / inverse;
            verts[i].z = Mathf.RoundToInt(verts[i].z*inverse) / inverse;
        }
        mesh.vertices = verts;
    }

    public static void Weld (this Mesh mesh, float threshold, float bucketStep) {
        Vector3[] oldVertices = mesh.vertices;
        Vector3[] newVertices = new Vector3[oldVertices.Length];
        int[] old2new = new int[oldVertices.Length];
        int newSize = 0;

        // Find AABB
        Vector3 min = new Vector3 (float.MaxValue, float.MaxValue, float.MaxValue);
        Vector3 max = new Vector3 (float.MinValue, float.MinValue, float.MinValue);
        for (int i = 0; i < oldVertices.Length; i++) {
            if (oldVertices[i].x < min.x) min.x = oldVertices[i].x;
            if (oldVertices[i].y < min.y) min.y = oldVertices[i].y;
            if (oldVertices[i].z < min.z) min.z = oldVertices[i].z;
            if (oldVertices[i].x > max.x) max.x = oldVertices[i].x;
            if (oldVertices[i].y > max.y) max.y = oldVertices[i].y;
            if (oldVertices[i].z > max.z) max.z = oldVertices[i].z;
        }
        min -= Vector3.one * 0.111111f;
        max += Vector3.one * 0.899999f;

        // Make cubic buckets, each with dimensions "bucketStep"
        int bucketSizeX = Math.Max(1, Mathf.FloorToInt ((max.x - min.x) / bucketStep) + 1);
        int bucketSizeY = Math.Max(1, Mathf.FloorToInt ((max.y - min.y) / bucketStep) + 1);
        int bucketSizeZ = Math.Max(1, Mathf.FloorToInt ((max.z - min.z) / bucketStep) + 1);
        List<int>[,,] buckets = new List<int>[bucketSizeX, bucketSizeY, bucketSizeZ];

        // Make new vertices
        for (int i = 0; i < oldVertices.Length; i++) {
            // Determine which bucket it belongs to
            int x = Mathf.FloorToInt ((oldVertices[i].x - min.x) / bucketStep);
            int y = Mathf.FloorToInt ((oldVertices[i].y - min.y) / bucketStep);
            int z = Mathf.FloorToInt ((oldVertices[i].z - min.z) / bucketStep);

            // Check to see if it's already been added
            if (buckets[x, y, z] == null)
                buckets[x, y, z] = new List<int> (); // Make buckets lazily

            for (int j = 0; j < buckets[x, y, z].Count; j++) {
                Vector3 to = newVertices[buckets[x, y, z][j]] - oldVertices[i];
                if (Vector3.SqrMagnitude (to) < 0.001f) {
                    old2new[i] = buckets[x, y, z][j];
                    goto skip; // Skip to next old vertex if this one is already there
                }
            }

            // Add new vertex
            newVertices[newSize] = oldVertices[i];
            buckets[x, y, z].Add (newSize);
            old2new[i] = newSize;
            newSize++;

            skip:;
        }

        // Make new triangles
        int[] oldTris = mesh.triangles;
        int[] newTris = new int[oldTris.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < oldTris.Length; i++) {
            newTris[i] = old2new[oldTris[i]];
        }

        Vector3[] finalVertices = new Vector3[newSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
            finalVertices[i] = newVertices[i];

        mesh.Clear();
        mesh.vertices = finalVertices;
        mesh.triangles = newTris;

        // Debug.LogFormat("Weld vert count: {0} vs. {1}", newSize, oldVertices.Length);
    }


    public static void Simplify(this MeshCollider meshCollider) { meshCollider.sharedMesh.Simplify(); }
    public static void Simplify(this Mesh mesh) {
        var verts = mesh.vertices;
        var origNumVerts = verts.Length;

        var workingSet = new List<Vertice>(origNumVerts);
        for (int i = 0; i < origNumVerts; i++) {
            var r = new Vertice();
            r.position = verts[i];
            workingSet.Add(r);
        }

        var tris = mesh.triangles;
        var triLength = tris.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < triLength; i+=3)
            Face.AddFace(workingSet, tris, i);

        for (int i = 0; i < origNumVerts; i++)
            workingSet[i].AssignLinearPosition();


        /*********************************
         *                               *
         *         Simplify mesh!        *
         *                               *
         ********************************/

        HashSet<Vertice> candidates;
        HashSet<Vertice> nextCandidates  = new HashSet<Vertice>();

        foreach (Vertice v in workingSet) if (!v.IsStatic)
            nextCandidates.Add(v);

        while (nextCandidates.Count != 0) {
            candidates = nextCandidates;
            nextCandidates = new HashSet<Vertice>();
            foreach (Vertice a in candidates) {
                if (a.edges != null) foreach (Edge ac in a.edges) {
                        Vertice c;
                        if (a.CanFollow(ac, out c)) {
                            foreach (Face f in ac.faces)
                                Edge.Collapse(f.GetOpposite(c), f.GetOpposite(a), f);
                            for (int i = a.edges.Count-1; i >= 0; --i) {
                            //foreach (Edge edge_of_a in a.edges) {
                                if (a.edges[i] != ac) {
                                    var o = a.edges[i].GetOpposite(a);
                                    if (!o.IsStatic) nextCandidates.Add(o);
                                    a.edges[i].Reconnect(a, c);
                                }
                            }
                            if (!c.IsStatic) nextCandidates.Add(c);

                            c.DisconnectFrom(ac);
                            a.Disconnect();
                            ac.DisconnectIncludingFaces();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }

        var simplifiedVerts = new List<Vertice>();
        foreach (Vertice v in workingSet) if (v.edges != null)
            simplifiedVerts.Add(v);

        var simplifiedNumVerts = simplifiedVerts.Count;
        var newPositions = new Vector3[simplifiedNumVerts];
        //var resultColors = new Color[simplifiedNumVerts];
        for (int i = 0; i < simplifiedNumVerts; i++) {
            simplifiedVerts[i].finalIndex = i;
            newPositions[i] = simplifiedVerts[i].position;
        }

        var resultTris = new List<int>();
        var triSet = new HashSet<Face>();
        foreach (Vertice v in simplifiedVerts) {
            foreach (Edge e in v.edges) {
                foreach (Face f in e.faces) if (!triSet.Contains(f)) {
                        triSet.Add(f);
                        f.GetIndexes(resultTris);
                    }
            }
        }

        mesh.Clear();
        mesh.vertices = newPositions;
        mesh.triangles = resultTris.ToArray();

        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
        ;

        // Debug.LogFormat("Simplify vert count: {0} vs. {1}", simplifiedNumVerts, origNumVerts);
    }

    private class Vertice {
        public List<Edge> edges = new List<Edge>();
        public Vector3 position;

        /// <summary>A cache used for identifying a vertice during mesh reconstruction.
        public int finalIndex;

        /// <summary>
        ///  - Null if vertice is internal in a plane
        ///  - A non-zero vector if vertice is internal in a line
        ///  - Vector3.zero otherwise.
        /// </summary>
        public Vector3? linearPosition;

        public void AssignLinearPosition() {
            for (int i = 0; i < edges.Count; i++) {
                var edge = edges[i];
                if (!edge.HasEqualPlanes()) {
                    if (linearPosition == null)
                        linearPosition = edge.vertices[1].position - edge.vertices[0].position;
                    else if (!edge.IsParallel(linearPosition)) {
                        linearPosition = Vector3.zero;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsStatic { get {
                return linearPosition == Vector3.zero;
            } }

        public Edge GetExistingConnectingEdge(Vertice v) {
            foreach (Edge e in edges) {
                if (e.vertices[0] == this && e.vertices[1] == v) return e;
                if (e.vertices[1] == this && e.vertices[0] == v) return e;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public Edge GetConnectingEdge(Vertice v) {
            Edge result = GetExistingConnectingEdge(v);
            if (result == null) {
                result = new Edge(this, v);
                edges.Add(result);
                v.edges.Add(result);
            }
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>When collapsing an edge a->c, the linear space must
        /// be respected, and all faces, not connected with a->c,
        /// must not flip.
        /// </summary>
        public bool CanFollow(Edge transportEdge, out Vertice opposite) {
            if (IsStatic) { opposite = default(Vertice); return false; }
            if (linearPosition != null && !transportEdge.IsParallel(linearPosition)) { opposite = default(Vertice); return false; }

            var localTris = new HashSet<Face>();
            foreach (Edge e in edges) foreach (Face f in e.faces)
                localTris.Add(f);

            localTris.ExceptWith(transportEdge.faces);

            opposite = transportEdge.GetOpposite(this);
            var targetPos = opposite.position;
            var lTriEnum = localTris.GetEnumerator();
            try {
                while (lTriEnum.MoveNext())
                    if (lTriEnum.Current.MoveWouldFlip(this, targetPos))
                        return false;
            } finally { lTriEnum.Dispose(); }
            return true;
        }

        public void DisconnectFrom(Edge e) {
            edges.Remove(e);
        }

        public void Disconnect() {
            edges.Clear();
            edges = null;
        }

    }

    private class Edge {
        public List<Vertice> vertices;
        public List<Face> faces;

        public static void Collapse(Edge moved, Edge target, Face f) {
            Face faceOutsideMoved;
            try { faceOutsideMoved = moved.GetOpposite(f); }
            catch (Exception e) {
                foreach (Vertice v in moved.vertices) {
                    v.edges.Remove(moved);
                }
                //throw new Exception(e.Message + "\n" + moved.vertices[0].position + " <--> " + moved.vertices[1].position);
                return;
            }
            faceOutsideMoved.Replace(moved, target);
            target.Replace(f, faceOutsideMoved);
            foreach (Vertice v in moved.vertices) {
                v.edges.Remove(moved);
            }
        }

        public Edge(Vertice v0, Vertice v1) {
            vertices = new List<Vertice>(2);
            vertices.Add(v0);
            vertices.Add(v1);
            faces = new List<Face>(2);
        }

        public Vertice GetOpposite(Vertice v) {
            var v0 = vertices[0];
            return v != v0 ? v0 : vertices[1];
        }

        public Face GetOpposite(Face v) {
            if (faces.Count != 2) {
                throw new Exception ("Collapsing an edge with only 1 face into another. This is not supported.");
            }
            var face0 = faces[0];
            return face0 == v ? faces[1] : face0;
        }

        public bool HasEqualPlanes() {
            if (faces.Count != 2) return false;
            var f0   = faces[0];
            var f0e0 = faces[0].edges[0];

            var f1   = faces[1];
            var f1e0 = faces[1].edges[0];

            var e0 = f0e0 != this ? f0e0 : f0.edges[1];
            var e1 = f1e0 != this ? f1e0 : f1.edges[1];

            var v0 =    vertices[1].position -    vertices[0].position;
            var v1 = e0.vertices[1].position - e0.vertices[0].position;
            var v2 = e1.vertices[1].position - e1.vertices[0].position;

            var n0 = Vector3.Cross(v0, v1);

            var dot = Vector3.Dot(n0, v2);
            return -5e-3 < dot && dot < 5e-3;
        }

        public void Replace (Face oldFace, Face newFace) {
            for (int j = 0; j < faces.Count; j++) {
                if (faces[j] == oldFace) {
                    faces[j] = newFace;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Reconnect(Vertice oldVertice, Vertice newVertice) {
            if (vertices[0] == oldVertice) vertices[0] = newVertice;
            else                           vertices[1] = newVertice;
            newVertice.edges.Add(this);
        }

        public bool Contains(Vertice v) {
            return v == vertices[0] || v == vertices[1];
        }

        public bool IsParallel(Vector3? nv) {
            var v0 = vertices[0].position;
            var v1 = vertices[1].position;
            float cross = Vector3.Cross(v1 - v0, nv.Value).sqrMagnitude;
            return -5e-6f < cross && cross < 5e-6f;
        }

        public void DisconnectIncludingFaces() {
            vertices.Clear();
            vertices = null;
            foreach (Face f in faces)
                f.Disconnect();
            faces.Clear();
            faces = null;
        }
    }

    private class Face {
        public Edge[] edges;

        /*
         * <paramref name="e0">Edge between v0 and v1</paramref>
         * <paramref name="e1">Edge between v0 and v2</paramref>
         * <paramref name="e2">Edge between v1 and v2</paramref>
         */
        private Face(Edge e0, Edge e1, Edge e2) {
            edges = new Edge[] { e0, e1, e2 };
        }

        /*
         * <paramref name="allVertices">List of vertices, in the same order as 'verts' from the mesh.</paramref>
         * <paramref name="tris">The tris array from the mesh.</paramref>
         * <paramref name="triIndex">The index of the first vertex in this triangle.</paramref>
         */
        public static void AddFace(List<Vertice> allVertices, int[] tris, int triIndex) {
            var v0 = allVertices[tris[triIndex+0]];
            var v1 = allVertices[tris[triIndex+1]];
            var v2 = allVertices[tris[triIndex+2]];

            var e0 = v0.GetConnectingEdge(v1);
            var e1 = v0.GetConnectingEdge(v2);
            var e2 = v1.GetConnectingEdge(v2);

            var face = new Face(e0, e1, e2);

            e0.faces.Add(face);
            e1.faces.Add(face);
            e2.faces.Add(face);
        }

        public Edge GetOpposite(Vertice v) {
            Edge e0, e1;
            if (!(e0 = edges[0]).Contains(v)) return e0;
            if (!(e1 = edges[1]).Contains(v)) return e1;
            return edges[2];
        }

        public Vertice GetOpposite(Edge o) {
            var o0 = o.vertices[0];
            var o1 = o.vertices[1];
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // Will never reach 3 because there will be an unequal vertice before the third edge
                Edge e = edges[i];
                Vertice e0 = e.vertices[0];
                if (e0 != o0 && e0 != o1) return e0;
                Vertice e1 = e.vertices[1];
                if (e1 != o0 && e1 != o1) return e1;
            }
            throw new Exception("A face seems to have three edges that all share a vertice with a given edge.");
        }

        public void Replace (Edge oldEdge, Edge newEdge) {
            if      (edges[0] == oldEdge) edges[0] = newEdge;
            else if (edges[1] == oldEdge) edges[1] = newEdge;
            else                          edges[2] = newEdge;
        }

        public bool MoveWouldFlip(Vertice v, Vector3 p) {
            Edge oppositeEdge = GetOpposite(v);
            var ov0 = oppositeEdge.vertices[0].position;
            var ov  = oppositeEdge.vertices[1].position - ov0;
            var ot = p          - ov0;
            var ct = v.position - ov0;

            var cross0 = Vector3.Cross(ot, ov);
            var c0SqrMagnitude = cross0.sqrMagnitude;
            if (c0SqrMagnitude < 0.0001f) return true;

            var cross1 = Vector3.Cross(ct, ov);
            var c1SqrMagnitude = cross1.sqrMagnitude;
            if (c1SqrMagnitude < 0.0001f) return true;

            if (Mathf.Sign(Vector3.Dot(cross0, cross1)) < 0f) return true;

            return false;
        }

        /*
         * <summary>Adds the finalIndex for the verts in order: v0, v1, v2.</summary>
         */
        public void GetIndexes(List<int> results) {
            results.Add(GetOpposite(edges[2]).finalIndex);
            results.Add(GetOpposite(edges[1]).finalIndex);
            results.Add(GetOpposite(edges[0]).finalIndex);
        }

        public void Disconnect() {
            edges = null;
        }
    }
}
```

It works well for simplifying tile based meshes if the mesh is simple and uses cubes, like this:

[image: Mesh Image]

However, if I try to use it for a more complicated mesh, I get errors.

There's the

> Exception: A face seems to have three edges that all share a vertice with a given edge

As well as some null references that go `MeshColliderTools.cs:350 -> MeshColliderTools.cs:143`, or `MeshColliderTools.cs:293 -> MeshColliderTools.cs:137` or `MeshColliderTools.cs:415 -> MeshColliderTools.cs:440 -> MeshColliderTools.cs:265 -> MeshColliderTools.cs:135`

Here's what the more complicated mesh looks like:

[image: Complicated Mesh]

Answer (score 0):

Mesh decimation/simplification is one of the most difficult things to get right. There are so many possible edge-cases which will break your code.

Looking through your code, it appears that you've accounted for the possibility of boundary edges (an edge with only 1 facet attached to it), but you haven't considered the possibility of non-manifold edges (edge with more than 2 facets attached to it). I see that you have several assertions that the number of faces == 2, which theoretically would prevent issues with non-manifold edges.

However, it's possible to produce non-manifold edges by collapsing an edge. This will always occur if the local region being collapsed is not homeomorphic to a disk (i.e., you can't lay the local geometry around the collapsing edge flat).

Whenever I write mesh-manipulation code, my debugging strategy is always the same:

Save off each iteration of collapse and then look at the last file which successfully collapsed. Most likely, you'll see non-manifold geometry. Trace back where that non-manifold edge snuck in, and then run through that collapse line-by-line in your debugger and find where your code allows it through. Then, patch that section of the code to account for non-manifold edges and wait until you find another mesh which utterly breaks your code.

In my experience, I've found it's better to just use someone else's existing mesh structure. [This StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32145638/7564109) mentions an open-source implementation which claims to be robust. It might be worth a look.

Comment: That library doesn't seem to work, it's full of errors and won't compile. Even tried fixing a few of them (lot of simple stuff like duplicates) but it seems pretty borked.

Comment: well that's a shame... Unfortunately, I don't think I'll be too much help beyond the debugging tips then. I've always coded this stuff in C++, and there are plenty of libraries (such as libIGL, CGAL, etc.). It's bizarre to me that there don't appear to be any such geometry libraries in C#